# Bracket.io issues + System Monitor issue

Tags: system-monitor, adobe-brackets

Just like the title says. I included pictures regarding the issues I am having. I am a Win 10 user, but I am in love with Ubuntu, but these problems are making me uncomfortable especially with a new OS. Please help.

[Brackets.io issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXJ1A.png)

Comment: Hi Kazzko. Is the problem that you think memory usage is too high? Please verify what processes are using the most memory: Open Terminal and enter the command `top`, press `Shift`+`m`, then `q` to quit; finally, copy-paste the output into your question.

Comment: I fixed the System Monitor issue. It's caused by communitheme theme. But, the Brackets.io seems like a real issue, because I get Ubuntu report dialog regarding Brackets... It's my favorite app to use for Web Dev.

Comment: That's good you fixed your problem with the System Monitor. I'm still not clear, though, on what your problem with Brackets is. Can you explain what the problem you're having is? The first screenshot you linked to just looks like a normal window for an active application. The second screenshot is a picture of your System Monitor identical to the third screenshot.

Comment: I have updated my post. Look how the font looks a bit weird, as if it was rendered with fault.

Comment: I see. Which font looks weird to you--the font the code of the HTML document is displayed in, or the system font (the font in the title bar menus, etc)? If you're confused about why the index.html file is being displayed as code and not as an HTML document, you need to preview the document to see it as it would look if it were a website, with all the formatting and links and everything. Brackets is a text editor, so that's what you see when you open an HTML document in the program--its code (text). Just turn live preview on.

Comment: The HTML code's text looks weird. I know how to use the program, and I know what a code looks like. But the code's font isn't clean /clear. Look carefully, you will see dots and small dashes next to the code's letters.

Comment: Pardon my misunderstanding. You didn't actually explain what your problem was until just now in your last comment. If I zoom in to 200% I can see what you're talking about.